# AS3 reference custom property in a custom class for a library symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

So I've done a fair amount of searching through SO and couldn't quite find the answer to this question. I have a movieclip in my symbol library that's exported for actionscript, and I've written a custom class for it. It mostly works great except for when I try to access a custom private property after I've added the movieclip to the stage. Below's an example:

```
package {

    public class MyMovieClip extends MovieClip {

        private var _isEnabled:Boolean = false;

        public function MyMovieClip():void {

            trace(this);
        }

        public function set isEnabled( b:Boolean ):void {

            _isEnabled = b;
        }

        public function get isEnabled():Boolean {

            return _isEnabled;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have another class where I am adding instances of the movieclip to the stage in a loop:

```
package {

    public class MyOtherClass extends MovieClip {

        public var myMC:MyMovieClip;
        public var docClass:*;

        public function MyOtherClass( docRef:* ):void { // passing in a reference to the DocumentClass so I can access the stage
            docClass = docRef;
            init();
        }

        public function init():void {

            for(var i:int=0; i<6; i++) {

                var myMC:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip; // instantiate the movieclip which is exported for actionscript and has a custom class 
                //set a few native properties
                myMC.name = "myMC" + i; //setting the name so I can reference this movieclip after it's been added to stage
                myMC.y = myMC.height * i + 20;
                myMC.x = 20;
                myMC.alpha = .7;
            }

            dispatchEvent(new Event(MyOtherClass.MOVIECLIPS_ADDED)); // just to be safe, let's dispatch a custom event when all movieclips have been added
        }

        public function traceEnabled():void {

            trace(docClass.stage.getChildByName("myMC1").isEnabled); // this throws: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property isEnabled through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

        }
    }
}
```

And finally I instantiate MyOtherClass inside my document class:

```
package {

    public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {

        public var myOtherClass:MyOtherClass;

        public function DocumentClass():void {

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        public function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {

            myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(); // upon instantiation, init is called in MyOtherClass and all of my movieclips are added to the sage
        }
    }
}
```

What gives? Why can't I access the MyMovieClip property, isEnabled, after it's been added to the stage? Is there another way? (Thanks in advance for any help)

Comment: You don't actually add it to stage. Also, getChildByName returns a DisplayObject item, so perhaps you're missing a cast. Try 'var className:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName( yourObject );', see what's the type of the object you just added. Or you know, just run the debugger and see what properties your object has in the Locals window.

Comment: as @Trickery mentions, you're not adding the objects to stage. Try replacing `var myMC:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip;` with `var myMC:MyMovieClip = docClass.stage.addChild(new MyMovieClip() as MyMovieClip;` and also, when tracing, don't forget to cast:`trace(MyMovieClip(docClass.stage.getChildByName("myMC1")).isEnabled);`

Comment: Why are you even using `getChildByName`?  The above commenters are right, your error is because your looking for isEnabled on a displayObject, casting it as MyMovieClip will fix your problem.  Do away with getChildByName and use events instead that have direct references to your object through their `currentTarget`/`target ` parameters.

Comment: @Trickery & George Profenza - I made an answer, but if either of you who were here first want to make one, I will delete it so you can get the credit.

Comment: Sorry about that. Forgot to include addChild. I rewrote what I'm actually trying to do for simplification. Thank you so much for all of your answers. I'll review and get back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally all children of a `DisplayObjectContainer` are referenced as `DisplayObject`, so when you use `getChildByName`, it returns a DisplayObject.

In order to access your custom properties without causing a compile-time error, you would need to cast the result of `getChildByName` as the Class of your custom properties. See the code below.

That however isn't your only issue (though it's the reason for the error, once you correct you will get runtime errors as well).

In your creation loop, your not adding `myMC` to the display list, so calling stage.getChildByName() will return null because your clips aren't on the stage.

Your also not adding your myOtherClass to the display list in the posted code.

Also, storing a reference to the document class isn't really needed. Just add the addedToStage listener in `MyOtherClass` and have the handler be init.

HERE IS SOME UPDATED CODE
For your `MyOtherClass`:

```
    public function MyOtherClass():void { 
        if(stage){
            init(); //if stage is ready, call init, if not wait for the added to stage event
        }else{
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }
    }

    public function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);

        for(var i:int=0; i<6; i++) {

            var myMC:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip;
            myMC.name = "myMC" + i; //setting the name so I can reference this movieclip after it's been added to stage
            myMC.y = myMC.height * i + 20;
            myMC.x = 20;
            myMC.alpha = .7;

            addChild(myMC); //!!!! add to the displayList
        }

        dispatchEvent(new Event(MyOtherClass.MOVIECLIPS_ADDED)); // just to be safe, let's dispatch a custom event when all movieclips have been added
    }

    public function traceEnabled():void {
        var myMC:MyMovieClip = this.getChildByName("myMC1") as MyMovieClip; //!!! cast it as MyMovieClip so you have access to all the properties/methods in that class
        if(myMC){  //myMC will be null if the cast failed
            trace(myMC.isEnabled); 
        }
    }

    /*
       getChildByName is slow and cumbersome. Most people generally only use it for accessing things put on the timeline in the Flash IDE.  Using events is a much better way of accessing your items. If traceEnabled was caused by a mouse event attached to myMC, then this would be a much better implementation:
    */
    public function betterTraceEnabled(e:Event):void {
        var myMC:MyMovieClip = e.currentTarget as MyMovieClip;
        if(myMC){
            trace(myMC.isEnabled);
        }
    }
```

AND YOUR DOCUMENT CLASS:

```
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip {

    public var myOtherClass:MyOtherClass;

    public function DocumentClass():void {

        if(stage){
            onAddedToStage(null); //most of the time stage is already populated in the constructor of your document class
        }else{
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }
    }

    public function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {

        myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(); // upon instantiation, init is called in MyOtherClass and all of my movieclips are added to the sage
        addChild(myOtherClass); //add it to the displayList
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I'll test this out and let you know how it goes. Oh, and the MyOtherClass is not really a DisplayObject. It's meant to be a View Class. It doesn't extend a library symbol or anything. So must I really add it to the DisplayList?

Comment: You could bybass it and add the myMC objects directly to the stage. (and pass in the stage object in the constructor like you were before).  The code is just cleaner (and slightly faster) when you're using the stage object that is defined in it's own class scope.  If you don't ever add it to the stage (MyOtherClass),then you shouldn't have it extend MovieClip. As it is, if there is no timeline functions being used, you should have it extend Sprite instead of MovieClip, as it's less overhead.